# jitter-facet-pointrange: Control alpha of point and range in geom_pointrange()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a jittering / geom_pointrange /faceting problem. I'm trying to plot a numeric variable with confidence intervals on the y-axis and a factor variable on the x-axis.  Additional complication: I need to facet, and the facets have different levels of the factor variable.

I can get REALLY close with geom_pointrange(), but I can't seem to control the alpha level of the point and the range separately.

If I do this:

```
y = rnorm(1000)
uis = y + 1
lis = y - 1
covariate <- rep(c("Gender", "Party"), each=N/2)
covariate_level <- rep(c("M", "F", "Dem", "Ind", "Rep" ), 
                       times=c(100, 400, 250, 100, 150))
df <- data.frame(y, uis, lis, covariate, covariate_level)

ggplot(df, aes(x=covariate_level, y=y)) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(), alpha=.5) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin=lis, ymax=uis), position = position_jitter(), alpha=.05) +
  facet_wrap(~covariate, scale="free_x")
```

the points and the ranges have different jitters.

if I do:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=covariate_level, y=y)) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin=lis, ymax=uis), position = position_jitter(), alpha=.1) + 
  facet_wrap(~covariate, scale="free_x")
```

It's really hard to see the points.

One solution that I can't get work is to add jitter to the x variable, i.e., make it numeric and then fix up the labels on the x axis -- can't seem to fix the labels because of the faceting.

Comment: I spent some time looking at this, but I can't tell well enough what's wrong with what you've tried and what your desired output is to be of much help.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it.  The trouble with the first way (`geom_point` plus `geom_linerange`) is that the jitters for the elements don't match (points get disconnected from their confidence intervals.) The trouble with the second wave (`geom_pointrange`) is that the alpha level is the same for the points and the confidence intervals.  My desired output would have them be different.  To summarize: with a factor variable on the x axis, I need the same jitter but different alpha levels.